# direct http to https on certain pages?

Tags: ssl, https

Hi I have added the below code to .ht access but how can I add another page to this? such as login.php

also if the user types in www. they get a "untrusted connection" as the SSL is only valid without the www.  how could I fix this?

Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login.html
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: You will get better help at serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question doesn't really give the required information to write the rewrite rule. Upon what criteria do you want to redirect them to login.php?

As far as the SSL issue;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://$1 [L]
```

Comment: the login form is login.html....this is processed through login.php , so if the user types http is should be changed to https

Comment: Also the code above I either get internal server error, or untrusted connection

Answer (score 0):

This way is very useful for my personal blog page

i'm add this code to .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Good Luck and Thanks,

[Belajar Internet Marketing](https://betariko.com/cara-redirect-https-ke-http/)